# How to join tables together via Ids using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, inner-join

I am having trouble joining parts of tables. I want first and last names of the people and whatever their interest is to be joined together. I get this error message: "[1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (ambiguous column name: pi.PersonID)"

```
CREATE TABLE people (
PersonID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
FirstName VARCHAR(100),
LastName VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO people (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES ('Walter', 'White'),
       ('Jesse', 'Pinkman'),
       ('Saul', 'Goodman');

SELECT * FROM people;

CREATE TABLE interests (
     InterestID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     Interest VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO interests (Interest)
values ('Swimming'),
       ('Basketball'),
       ('Running');

SELECT * FROM interests;

CREATE TABLE persons_interests (
    PersonID INTEGER,
    InterestID INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonID, InterestID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES people,
    FOREIGN KEY (InterestID) REFERENCES interests
);

DROP TABLE persons_interests;

INSERT INTO persons_interests (PersonID, InterestID)
VALUES (1, 3),
   (2, 2),
   (3, 3);

SELECT * FROM persons_interests;

SELECT FirstName, LastName, Interest FROM people p, interests i
JOIN persons_interests pi on p.PersonID = pi.PersonID
JOIN persons_interests pi on i.Interest = pi.InterestID;
```

Comment: Please include the output you expect here and explain why you expect it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't `DROP TABLE persons_interests;`

Comment: ^^ is that a copy&paste error? I would expect the `INSERT INTO persons_interests` to fail if not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix implicit an explicit joins! You seem to want:

```
select p.firstname, p.lastname, i.interest 
from people p
inner join persons_interests pi on pi.personid = p.personid
inner join interests i on i.interestid = pi.interestid;
```

Here, each table appears just once in the `from` clause, with the relevant join conditions.

Comment: What is the difference between join and inner join?

Comment: @NicholasChill: that's the same thing, really (`inner` is optional, I just took the habit of using it). The real difference between this query and your original code is the way the joins are built. There are no implicit joins anymore, and each table is joined just once.

Comment: Can you join on a table that has been dropped?